# how to redirect url to root folder

Tags: linux, .htaccess, ubuntu

I need to access root folder from web url

my domain is for example : https://myname.com

i have few files under root i am using ubuntu

example(folder name in root location) : pod

i need to access this root folder https://myname.com/pod/

please help me how to do this

i created folder "pod" in my var/www/html/ and tried to redirect to root folder pod but it didn't work

i tried the followed way

```
sudo Redirect permanent /pod/ https://myname.net/pod/
sudo: Redirect: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rule cannot be run using `sudo`.

Place this rule in `/var/www/html/pod/.htaccess`

```
RedirecetMatch 301 ^ /
```

Then try visiting `http://example.com/pod/`